# Could not find a part of the path using File.Copy(source,destination,true) in C# console app

Tags: file, c#-4.0, exception, path, copy

I continue to get the (Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users(user profile)\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\E!PC\Macros) exception.  The directory is there on the drive but im not sure why i continue to get this exception.

```
Extra6DestPath = "C:\Users\(user profile)\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\E!PC\Macros\"

static void copyMacrosAndBitmaps(string ExtraSourcePath, string Extra6xDestPath )
    {
        //counter for total Macro count on network
        int Count = 0;
        //counter for total bitmap count on network
        int iCount = 0;

        //Get File information to use for copy 
        FileInfo[] macrosArray;
        FileInfo[] iconArray;

        //Get Directory information to use for copy 
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ExtraSourcePath);
        DirectoryInfo diIcon = new DirectoryInfo(ExtraIconPath);

        //set all macro paths as a string from directory into an array
        macrosArray = di.GetFiles("*.ebm");
        Count = macrosArray.Length;

        //set all bitmaps from directory into an array
        iconArray = diIcon.GetFiles("*.bmp");
        iCount = iconArray.Length;

        //copy macros into destination folder
        if (Count == 0)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No Macros found to copy");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                File.Copy(Extra6xSourcePathW7 + macrosArray[i].ToString(), Extra6xDestPath + iconArray[i].Name, true);                
            }
            //Copy the bitmaps into destination folder
            if (iCount == 0)
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("No bitmaps found to copy");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
                {
                    File.Copy(ExtraIconPath + iconArray[i].ToString(), Extra6xDestPath + iconArray[i].Name, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: File.Copy(Extra6xSourcePathW7 + macrosArray[i].ToString(), Extra6xDestPath + macrosArray[i].name, true);       I missed the part in the API where the destination cannot be a directory and had to be a specific file name. Hope this atleast helps save someone else from the headache i have had while looking this over!!

Comment: edited code above to be the correctly functioning version!!  Happy Programming All!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first try declaring the path with @ symbol, to handle characters that need to be escaped:

```
Extra6DestPath = @"C:\Users\(user profile)\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\E!PC\Macros\"
```

Comment: You are correct... That is how i would do it but i have my values saved in App.Config and only showed it as hardcoded (and forgot the @) for simplicity sake.  I did figure out what I was doing wong though. I was trying to pass a directory as the destination but what the File.Copy method needs in the 2nd string Destination is the actual path AND filename to be stored as.  Being as I want to keep the same file names I just referenced the name atribute of the FileInfo Array at index i and concatonated it to the path I was already using.  Thanks a bunch for your quick answer to my question though!